# How to check JSON when coding locally

Tags: json, razor, localhost

Hi im coding JSON locally, and im unable to see the result. I've heard this might be a problem when coding locally, is this true, and if it is, is there a way to get around this without uploading it to a server every five minute or so.

Code on the page calling (default.cshtml)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ajax_get_json(){
        var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        hr.open("GET", "JSON.cshtml", true);
        hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json", true);
        hr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200){
                var data = JSON.parse(hr.responseText);
                var result = document.getElementById("results");
                result.innerHTML = "";
                for(var obj in data){
                    result.innerHTML += data[obj].item + "<br/>";
                }
            }
        }
        hr.send(null);
        result.innerHTML = "requesting...";
    }
</script>

<div>
    <script type="text/javascript">ajax_get_json();</script>
</div>
```

code on the page being called (JSON.cshtml)

```
{
@{
    var connection = DatabaseConnection.createConnection();
    int count = 0;
    DatabaseConnection.openConnection(connection);
    foreach(Varer v in Varer.getListAll(connection))
    {
        if(count > Varer.getListAll(connection).Count)
        {
            int id = v.id;
            string navn = v.navn;

            <text>
                "ul@v.id":{ "item":"@v.navn" },
            </text>
        }
        else
        {
            <text>
                "ul@v.id":{ "item":"@v.navn" }
            </text>
        }
    }
    DatabaseConnection.closeConnection(connection);
}
}
```

the two pages is on the same level. and is coded using cshtml

Comment: Please, post a code example...

Comment: just updated the question, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There's no issue, as long as you're not trying to use AJAX / WebSockets / et cetera, to get it into your program.

If you manually type:

```
var json = "{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":32}",
    data = JSON.parse(json);

data.name;
```

It's going to work just fine.

How you construct that JSON isn't going to matter at all, so long as it's valid.
Just don't expect to be able to get it in an AJAX call.

Comment: Why wont I be able to access it in an ajax call?

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard Quite simply, because the same browser security which prevents cross-domain access also prevents file-system access. You can stuff your JSON in a function-call and download it as a script, but then you've got to work that into your system. Setting up a server to point at 0.0.0.0 shouldn't be too time-consuming.